# Can I publish a ASP.NET Core app into an Azure AppService on a Linux Service Plan from Visual Studio?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I just need to deploy a aspnet core app into a Linux Service Plan.
I tried pre-creating the Linux service plan (into it's own Resource Group) from portal, and then starting the publish profile creating process in VS, but it does not show the linux Resource Group or Service Plan.
I can only find references to doing this from a Linux machine using Git-integration.

Thanks in advance,

Jose Parra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, for now we cannot deploy web app to Azure linux service plan through VS. It's by design that we can only see windows service plan in VS publish process.

However there are alternatives for us to choose.

- FTP-- Upload pre-compiled files(under ~/bin/Debug(Release) folder) to website. Here's the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service%2fcontainers%2ftoc.json).
- Local Git--You may have read this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-dotnetcore). Note that Git bash can also be used in Windows.
- GitHub--Follow this [reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/04/04/setting-up-and-using-github-in-visual-studio-2017/) to connect VS with your GitHub, then config Deployment option in portal. After that your code will be deployed automatically once pushed to GitHub.

There are some other deployment ways like CI/CD aka Continuous Delivery in portal and another source control tool BitBucket. I recommend you to use GitHub as it's simple to operate in VS after configuration.